# Puppet Delete Installer after Use

Tags: windows, puppet

Is it possible in puppet without ugly execs to delete an installer (in this case an exe) after it has been downloaded from the server and run. Basically the installer is fairly large, and I want to free up the disk space after installation.

Comment: How ever you do it, it will be more or less a hack - Puppet does not lend itself well to describing a **process** of what you want to happen, but rather a **state** that shall be established.

Comment: I understand that, I just would like to have the state be X installed without junk executables lying around.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
file { "installer file":
  path    => "/path/to/installer",
  ensure  => absent,
  require => Something["that the installer creates"]
}
```

Just make sure that the `file` object depends on something that is created by the installer: a package, a directory, or a file.

**EDIT:** There appears to be (at least in Puppet 3.4) a special resource class just for this purpose: `tidy`

```
tidy { "installer file":
  path    => "/path/to/installer",
  require => Something["that the installer creates"]
}
```

More info: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.4.latest/type.html#tidy

Comment: The problem with this, unless I am misunderstanding, is that the file I want to remove is the installer itself. I would already have declared a file resource with the same path, which is a nono.

Comment: You can instead delete the directory where you put the installer file, which will be a different resource.